# Execute files looping recursively through a directory with an exclusion

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file, how could i loop through all files under a folder and excluding folder "X" ?

Something like :

```
SET PWD=%~dp0
for /r "%PWD%foo" %%a in (*.sql) do (IF "%%~a" NEQ "%PWD%foo\X\*.sql" (echo %%a))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SET PWD=%~dp0
for /r "%PWD%foo" %%a in (.) do (IF "%%~a" NEQ "X" (echo %%a))
```

With the `if` statement, use `neq` to specify Not Equal To. Type `if /?` for more help.

Mona

Comment: I'm afraid this solution doesn't work. %%a is the path of the file in each iteration. I tried to adapt your suggestion and came up with this:                                                                @for /r "%PWD%foo" %%a in (*.sql) do (IF "%%~a" NEQ "%PWD%foo\X\*.sql" (echo %%a))

Comment: Ok my bad, i was missing a "\" between %PWD% and foo. I accepted your answer, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r "%PWD%foo" %%a in (.) do if not exist "%%~fa\X" echo %%~fa
```

Comment: This solution also works, but i accepted mona's since she was first. Thank you.